# Can't read all data from firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all the data from firebase.
I logged in successfully by authenticated users and I also got the response from the firebase for retrieving other information.

I attached my response here.
[image]

When I try to read addInfo, address, categories, 
I get undefined but when I am try to read $id at that time I get it.

So, I am only able to get $id, I can not read other details.

```
    $scope.loggedInUserData = addOffersService.getBusinessDetails(idd,"");
```

Now when I use:

```
console.log($scope.loggedInUserData)
```

then I get all the details.

But when I am trying to read

```
console.log($scope.loggedInUserData.addInfo); 
console.log($scope.loggedInUserData.address);
```

I get undefined.

```
    function getBusinessDetails(id,path) {
        var query = db.child('/business/'+id+'/'+path);
        return $firebaseObject(query);
    }
```

What is wrong with the response?

Comment: can you share your database structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from the Firebase database asynchronously. This means that when `getBusinessDetails ()` returns, the data hasn't completed loading yet. So you're logging the object when the data hasn't loaded yet.

When you log `$scope.loggedInUserData`, the JavaScript console knowns that you're logging the entire object and ensures that it updates when the loading has completed.

But when you log `$scope.loggedInUserData.addInfo`, there is no value to log. So you see `undefined` in that case.

I recommend reading more about this here:

- [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase) (which contains links to many more questions)
- [Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905600/best-way-to-retrieve-firebase-data-and-return-it-or-an-alternative-way)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [How to run multiple async functions then execute callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828415/how-to-run-multiple-async-functions-then-execute-callback)