# Generate multiple pdf in loop asynchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, html2pdf

I was trying to generate pdf files in a asynchronous way with html2pdf.js.

The generation of PDF files works very well but I would like the waiting process at the end of the geeneration of all the files to display the result in the elemé `Div.Alert`  with the list of generated files and their path access and hide the loading that everything is finished. Look function convertToPdf()

I wrote this code but there is what is wrong, thank you for your help

```
var envLabSub = ['env1', 'env2'];

//call function to convert in PDF
convertToPdf(msg, subject);

function convertToPdf(msg, subject) {
    envLabSub.forEach(async env => {
        await printer(msg, subject, env);
    })
        var message = "<h3><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span> Email was sent with success !!</h3>";

    $("div.alert").removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').html(message);
    $("div.alert").append("<ul></ul>");
    
    returArray.forEach(function (pdf) {
        $("div.alert ul").append("<li>File :<b>" + pdf.fileName + "</b> was created with success<br><a href='" + pdf.path + "' target='_blank'>" + pdf.path + "</a></ii>");
    });
    
    $("div.alert").show();
    $(".loading").hide();
}

async function printer(msg, subject, env) {

    var divToPrint = $('<div/>').append(msg);
    var versionTarget = $('#inpTargetVersion').val();
    var service = $('#Select_Service option:selected').text();
    var returArray = [];

    // date export Csv
    var MyDate = new Date();
    var datePdf = MyDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "_" + ('0' + MyDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ('0' + MyDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ('0' + MyDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    var fileName = datePdf + "_" + env.replace('/','_').trim() + "_" + service.trim() + "_" + versionTarget + ".pdf";
    
    var worker = html2pdf();
    await worker.from(divToPrint[0]);
    let myPdf = await worker.outputPdf('datauristring', 'mypdf.pdf');
  
    //this converts the uri to blob
    var preBlob = dataURItoBlob(myPdf);
    var file = new File([preBlob], fileName, {type: 'application/pdf'});
   
    // sends the message to api
    sendFile(file);
}

async function sendFile(userFiles) {
    let filePaths;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("filePdf", userFiles);
    let response = await fetch('views/ajax_response.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });
        
    filePaths = await response.json();
    return filePaths;
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Promise.all()`, and wrap the foreach loop with it. Like so:

```
    await Promise.all(envLabSub.forEach(async env => {
        await printer(msg, subject, env);
    }))
```

Similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828546/13190911

Comment: I tried to set up this method but I have the following error and I do not understand how to resolve it - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"