# Javascript execute async task one by one on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, promise

I have an array of url:

```
var myurls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
```

And I want to fetch all urls one by one.

I know how to do it manually, but not for an array

```
fetchUrl1(myurls[0])
  .then(function(){
    return test_func(myurls[1]);
  })
  .then(function(){
    return test_func(myurls[2]);
  })
  .then(function() {
     console.log('done');
   });
```

How I can do that dynamically ?

Comment: Do you want to call the same function or different function to fetch the urls?

Comment: See this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all) is a better dupe target.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, I'll remove my flag :)

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans It is not possible to remove flags. You can remove the comment but the flag remains.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for all of your reply I'll have a look at that but I want to fetch one by one because the size of my url is approximatly 20k or 30k ... this is very very big

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Comment: this is a little bit different in this case

Comment: i think you need to use a recursive function, called each time on success of the recent call.

Comment: @Ron That's intresting ... I will investigate this solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like there are some duplicate candidates in the comments, but nonetheless here is a concise answer that provides several methods depending on the specific requirements:

You can use asyncjs' [`eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) (if you want to use node-style callbacks) or bluebird's [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) if using promises to fetch the URLs in series. If you don't need the fetching to happen in series, but they can all be fetched in parallel, asyncjs' `each` and ES6's `Promise.all` will allow you to do that.

Both of these methods take functions as inputs, so you would take the original array of URLs and `map` them to the desired input functions and your final output would be an array of results (I'm assuming the responses from the URL fetching).

EDIT: including example code with Promise.each

```
var myurls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var myPromisifiedFetchRequests = myurls.map(url => fetch(url));

Promise.each(myPromisifiedFetchRequests).then(myFetchedResults => console.log(myFetchedResults));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is very specific because I want to use fetch

Comment: I'll try with Promise.each and update you, do you have an example of Pormise.each ?

Comment: I'm on react native

Comment: I updated my answer to provide example code as to how to use `Promise.each`. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you with react native I have a type error : Promise.each is not a function

Comment: Bluebird is a Library ok !

Comment: Yep sorry, i included a link to `Promise.each` documentation in the original answer :)

Comment: now with bluebird I have this error "expecting a function but got [object Undefined]"

Comment: When you `map` your array to become an array of promises, can you confirm the function you're using exists on page? Can you provide the line of code where you are `map`ing your array to become an array of promises?

Comment: let myPromisifiedFetchRequests = fetcher.shouldBeFetched.map(url => fetch(url)); This is this line (the same as you)

Comment: What this tells me is the function `fetch` is not defined on the page. Can you confirm, and make sure to use the correct function required to `fetch` the response from the URL? The main concept is that your array of URLs needs to be transformed into an Array of promises to be resolved. As long as that's happening, `Promise.each` should work as explained.

Comment: Without using bluebird you can also just do Promise.all()

Comment: Promise.all execute all of my task at the same time @MattAft ?

Comment: @LanceWhatley I have try 

      let myPromisifiedFetchRequests = fetcher.shouldBeFetched.map(url => {
        console.log(url);
        return fetch(url);
      });
      Promise.each(myPromisifiedFetchRequests).then(myFetchedResults => {
        console.log('test');
        console.log(myFetchedResults);
      });

This is my code, now, he don't print 'test' but it print all of my url and after that he print "Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Undefined]"

Comment: @user8026049 Yea, it does them in parallel. if you want the responses from the api requests then the promise returns an array of the responses in the order you listed them in the promise.all. It will resolve only when every action is successfully completed otherwise it will reject.

Comment: Oh ok I understand I don't want all task in parrallel, but just one by one

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this. It builds a chain of promises that will resolve with an array of all results in the order of the original array. Here's a JSFiddle if you want to play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/53r4oxyh/

```
//dummy http.get
function HttpGet(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`fetching ${url}`);
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(`done: ${url}`);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random()*500));
  });
}

function buildPromiseChain(items, func) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([]);
  });
  items.forEach((item) => {
    promise = promise.then((result) => {
      return func(item).then((itemResult) => {
        result.push(itemResult);
        return result;
      });
    });
  });
  return promise;
}

buildPromiseChain(myurls, HttpGet).then((results) => console.log('done', results));
```