# Promise.all returns before fetch has resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

With an array of Pokemon ids, I am hoping to get an array of Pokemon objects by fetching from the Pokemon API. The goal is to get from this

```
[1,2,3]
```

to this:

```
[
  {name: "ivysaur", weight: 130, …},
  {name: "venusaur", weight: 1000, …},
  {name: "bulbasaur", weight: 69, …}
]
```

I have taken a long hard look at this thread '[How can I fetch an array of urls with Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)' but none of the solutions are working for me. I have the same problem [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388310/2835005), but the solution proposed still does not yield results.

My `Promise.all` is fulfilling with an array of `undefined`s, instead of the Pokemons. Why?

```js
const pokemonIds = [1,2,3]

const pokemons = pokemonIds.map(id => {
 fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
   .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
       console.log(json)
          return json
    })
})

Promise.all(pokemons).then(res => {
 console.log('pokemon arr: ', res)
})
```

Comment: add a return before fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing return before `fetch`:

```
const pokemons = pokemonIds.map(id => {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json)
          return json
    })
});
```

or:

```
const pokemons = pokemonIds.map(id => 
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json)
          return json
    })
)
```