# Convert array of values to array of objects (key-value) pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, javascript-objects

Is there a simple way to convert an array of values:

```
dataset = [5, 10, 13];
```

to an array of objects, wherein each object is a key-value pair?

```
dataset = [ { key: 0, value: 5 },
            { key: 1, value: 10 },
            { key: 2, value: 13 } ];
```

This example is an abbreviated version of the dataset in the "Data Join with Keys" section of Scott Murray's Interactive Data Visualization for the Web, 2nd ed, p. 187.

I had trouble finding an answer, and therefore I am posting my own solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate the array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `Array.map()` accepts a callback that returns a new item. The 1st param is the original item (`value`), the 2nd is the index (`key`):

```js
const dataset = [5, 10, 13];

const result = dataset.map((value, key) => ({ key, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You beat me to it and yours is more elegant.  I had `dataset.map(function(d,i) {return {key: i, value: d}; } );`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `map`

```js
var dataset = [5, 10, 13]

var result = dataset.map((n, i) => ({ key: i, value: n }))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another alternative, `Array.from`

```js
var dataset = [5, 10, 13]

var result = Array.from(dataset, (n, i) => ({key: i, value: n}))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```