# Fetch doesn't store the values after the array for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, async-await, fetch-api

I want to add a description property to each object in the locations array that is fetched from Wikimedia API but when I log its value inside the loop it is there, but outside the loop, it gets erased.

I looked for solutions with async/await functions or Promise.all() but it didn't work out.

Is there a way to store the value properly to access it later ??

```js
let locations = [
    {
        latLng: [33.975561111111,28.555830555556],
        name: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
        searchTerm: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
        urlSerchTerm: 'Saint%20Catherine\'s%20Monastery'
    },
    {
        latLng: [29.91667,31.2],
        name: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
        searchTerm: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
        urlSerchTerm: 'Bibliotheca%20Alexandrina'
    }
];

async function fetchAsync (site, location) {
    // await response of fetch call
    let response = await fetch(site);
    // only proceed once promise is resolved
    let data = await response.json();
    // only proceed once second promise is resolved
    location.description = data[2][0];

    return location.description;
  }

// let fetches = [];
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    let site = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${locations[i].urlSerchTerm}&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*`;

    fetchAsync(site, locations[i])

}
console.log(locations[1].description)
```

Comment: Where do you actually append the result of `fetchAsync` into the `locations` array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Cloud_Ratha inside the fetchAsync function, the location.description is assigned to the result from the fetch response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a timing problem. Your `fetch` calls are getting executed **asynchronously** while the `console.log(...)` statement in the last line of your code snippet is being executed **synchronously**. In other words, the response to the requests issued by `fetch` will return after the `console.log(...)` and the `description` properties will still be undefined.

You can convince yourself of this by looking at the code below where the `console.log(...)` statement is wrapped in a timeout. Now the fetched description will be logged instead of `undefined`.

```js
let locations = [
    {
        latLng: [33.975561111111,28.555830555556],
        name: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
        searchTerm: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
        urlSerchTerm: 'Saint%20Catherine\'s%20Monastery'
    },
    {
        latLng: [29.91667,31.2],
        name: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
        searchTerm: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
        urlSerchTerm: 'Bibliotheca%20Alexandrina'
    }
];

async function fetchAsync (site, location) {
    // await response of fetch call
    let response = await fetch(site);
    // only proceed once promise is resolved
    let data = await response.json();
    // only proceed once second promise is resolved
    location.description = data[2][0];

    return location.description;
  }

// let fetches = [];
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    let site = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${locations[i].urlSerchTerm}&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*`;

    fetchAsync(site, locations[i])

}

window.setTimeout(() => {console.log(locations);}, 5000);
```

You can solve this with `Promise.all` as suggested by @JeremyThille. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711496/305949) explains the second use of `Promise.all` in case this is confusing.

```js
let locations = [
        {
            latLng: [33.975561111111,28.555830555556],
            name: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
            searchTerm: 'Saint Catherine\'s Monastery',
            urlSerchTerm: 'Saint%20Catherine\'s%20Monastery'
        },
        {
            latLng: [29.91667,31.2],
            name: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
            searchTerm: 'Bibliotheca Alexandrina',
            urlSerchTerm: 'Bibliotheca%20Alexandrina'
        }
    ];


    const fetchDescription = (location) => fetch(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${location.urlSerchTerm}&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*`);

    const descriptionRequests = locations.map(fetchDescription);
    Promise.all(descriptionRequests)
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
    .then(descriptions => {
      descriptions.forEach((description, index) => { locations[index].description = description[2][0]; });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(locations);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked after adding the setTimeout part around the code snippet that is using the description part.

Comment: @NouranSamy You're welcome. Do note that I was using a timeout to illustrate the problem and **not** suggesting that it's a viable solution. You should use `Promise.all` as suggested in @JeremyThille's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with `Promise.all` :

I'm creating an array of Promises by `.map`ping over the `locations` array.

```js
let locations = [
 {
  latLng: [33.975561111111, 28.555830555556],
  name: "Saint Catherine's Monastery",
  searchTerm: "Saint Catherine's Monastery",
  urlSerchTerm: "Saint%20Catherine's%20Monastery"
 },
 {
  latLng: [29.91667, 31.2],
  name: "Bibliotheca Alexandrina",
  searchTerm: "Bibliotheca Alexandrina",
  urlSerchTerm: "Bibliotheca%20Alexandrina"
 }
];

Promise.all(
    locations.map( location => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let site = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${location.urlSerchTerm}&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*`,
            response = await fetch(site),
            data = await response.json();
        location.description = data[2][0];
        // console.log("Got description = ", location.description)
        resolve();
    })))
.then(() => {
 console.log("locations[1].description = ", locations[1].description);
});
```

Comment: But when adding the console.log statement outside the .then function of the promise, it is undefined. The value is lost outside the promise.

Comment: @NouranSamy Yes, because the `console.log(...)` is being executed before the requests return.