# Fetching multiple files using Promises and Fetch API javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am updating my javascript skills with Promises, already have in place a library with XHR and callbacks to load and inject multiple files at once and only proceed if ALL of them succeeded.

I am trying to use Promise.all() and Fetch API to get a similar functionality but can't make it work: console.log('All the promises are resolved', values); always triggers no matter if some of the fetch promises failed.

I want to be able to execute the code below, and only proceed with nowInitialize function if all the files were able to be fetched, or throw error using catch() with the reason of the first file that failed

```
xRequire(['index.html', 'style.cds'])
  .then(nowInitialize)
  .catch(reason => 'One or more files failed to load' + reason)
```

style.cds will obviously fail

```
//TODO Handle file types appropriately
//TODO: Inject css, javascript files

function xRequire(files) {
    let urls = [];
    let promisesList = [];
    let handleAllPromises;


//Populates urls with each file required
for(let i=0; i < files.length ; i++) {
    urls.push(files[i]);
}
//Fetch each file in urls
urls.forEach( (url, i) => { // (1)
    promisesList.push(
        fetch(url)
            .then(handleResponse)
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    );
});

handleAllPromises = Promise.all(promisesList);
handleAllPromises.then(function(values) {
    console.log('All the promises are resolved', values);
});
handleAllPromises.catch(function(reason) {
    console.log('One of the promises failed with the following reason', reason);
});
}

function handleResponse(response) {
let contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
console.log('Requested Info: ' + contentType);
if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
    return handleJSONResponse(response);
} else if (contentType.includes('text/html')) {
    return handleTextResponse(response);
} else if (contentType.includes('text/css')) {
    return handleTextResponse(response);
} else if (contentType.includes('application/javascript')) {
    return handleTextResponse(response);
} else {
    throw new Error(`Sorry, content-type ${contentType} not supported`);
}
}

function handleJSONResponse(response) {
return response.json()
    .then(json => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return json;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(Object.assign({}, json, {
                status: response.status,
                statusText: response.statusText
            }));
        }
    });
}

function handleTextResponse(response) {
return response.text()
    .then(text => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return text;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject({
                status: response.status,
                statusText: response.statusText,
                err: text
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance your are not serious about this not being a duplicate right? I mean a simple search shows multiple dubs of dubs on SO ... come on. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all

Comment: @Akrion I didn't say that, I just said that `async/await` syntax issues aren't what the question is asking about (there are at least a couple issues going on in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in this way --with the only quirk i've found so far: *files* argument always needs to be an *array*, therefore always needs brackets when calling the function--

```
xRequire(['my-file'])
   .then(handle success)
   .catch(handle error);

async function xRequire(files) {
    let promises = [];
    let receivedData;

    //Iterate over files array and push results of fetch to promises array
    files.map(x => promises.push(fetch(x)));
    //populate receivedData array from promises array
    receivedData = await Promise.all(promises);
    //iterate over receivedData to handle each response accordingly
    return receivedData.map(x => handleResponse(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just rewrite it as async-await code? Here is a rough idea of the typical flow:

```
const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
  fetch(url1),
  fetch(url2),
  fetch(url3),
]);
```

In other words, `Promise.all()` returns the promise to all the data that is returned from your multiple `fetch()` functions.

Then, if you put this into a try-catch, you can handle the rejection as well:

```
try {
  const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(url1),
    fetch(url2),
    fetch(url3),
  ]);

  // Now you can process the data:
  [data1, data2, data3].map(handleResponse);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error downloading one or more files:', error);
}
```

If you want to loop with `async-await`, you can do that:

```
const promises = [];
for (const url of [url1, url2, url3, url4]) {
  promises.push(fetch(url));
}

const [data1, data2, data3, data4] = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: this seems great but I can't get the syntax working when looping through all the files being requested, for example xRequire(['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']), can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @aalvarado added

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First, you need to *return* the `Promise.all` call from `xRequire` in order to consume it in your `xRequire(..).then`:

```
return Promise.all(promisesList);
```

Also, when you use `.catch`, if a `Promise` is initially rejected, it will go into the `catch` block, do whatever code is there, *and then the `Promise` chain will **resolve*** (not reject) to whatever the `catch` block returns. If you want to percolate errors up the `Promise` chain, put your `catch` at the point in the chain at which you want to detect errors:

```
urls.forEach( (url, i) => { // (1)
  promisesList.push(
    fetch(url)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // no catch here
  );
});
```

I would suggest putting your `catch` *only in the caller* of `xRequire`, that way *it* will see all errors. Your `xRequire` function can be reduced to:

```
xRequire(['index.html', 'style.cds'])
  .then(nowInitialize)
  .catch(reason => 'One or more files failed to load' + reason)

function xRequire(files) {
  return Promise.all(
    urls.map(handleResponse)
  );
}
```

If you want the body of `xRequire` to be able to see errors, but you also want to percolate errors up the `Promise` chain, throw an error in a `catch` inside `xRequire`, so that the `Promise` it resolves to will *reject*, rather than resolve:

```
function xRequire(files) {
  return Promise.all(
    urls.map(handleResponse)
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('There was an error: ' + err);
    throw err;
  })
}
```

Comment: in your reduced function, can you point me where you actually fetch the files from server?