# How to return the Promise.all fetch api json data?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

How to I consume the Promise.all fetch api json data? It works fine to pull it if I don't use Promise.all. With .all it actually returns the values of the query in the console but for some reason I'm not able to access it. Here is my code and how it looks in the console after it resolves.

```
Promise.all([
    fetch('data.cfc?method=qry1', {
        method: 'post',
        credentials: "same-origin", 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: $.param(myparams0)
    }),
    fetch('data.cfc?method=qry2', {
        method: 'post',
        credentials: "same-origin", 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: $.param(myparams0)
    })
]).then(([aa, bb]) => {
    $body.removeClass('loading');
    console.log(aa);
    return [aa.json(),bb.json()]
})
.then(function(responseText){
    console.log(responseText[0]);

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

All I want is to be able to access data.qry1. I tried with responseText[0].data.qry1 or responseText[0]['data']['qry1'] but it returned undefined. This below is the output from console.log responseText[0]. The console.log(aa) gives Response {type: "basic" ...

```
    Promise {<resolved>: {…}}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
data: {qry1: Array(35)}
errors: []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aparently `aa.json()` and `bb.json()` are returned before being resolved, adding `async/await` to that will solve the problem :

```
.then(async([aa, bb]) => {
    const a = await aa.json();
    const b = await bb.json();
    return [a, b]
  })
```

```js
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
  ]).then(async([aa, bb]) => {
    const a = await aa.json();
    const b = await bb.json();
    return [a, b]
  })
  .then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);

  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

*Still looking for a better explaination though*

Comment: aa & bb are the response objects from the resolved requests. `.json()` is async itself and returns a promise with the resolved body content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Answer (score 22):

The simplest solution would be to repeat the use of `Promise.all`, to just wait for all `.json()` to resolve.
Just use :

```
Promise.all([fetch1, ... fetchX])
.then(results => Promise.all(results.map(r => r.json())) )
.then(results => { You have results[0, ..., X] available as objects })
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and my goal was to make the `Promise.all()` return an `array of JSON objects`.

```
let jsonArray = await Promise.all(requests.map(url => fetch(url)))
    .then(async (res) => {
        return Promise.all(
            res.map(async (data) => await data.json())
        )
    })
```

And if you need it very short (one liner for the copy paste people :)

```
const requests = ['myapi.com/list','myapi.com/trending']
const x = await Promise.all(requests.map(url=>fetch(url))).then(async(res)=>Promise.all(res.map(async(data)=>await data.json())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return [aa.json(),bb.json()]` use `return Promise.resolve([aa.json(),bb.json()])`. See documentation on [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)
.

Answer (score 0):

You can just throw `await` in front of your Promise instead of awaiting each individual fetch

```
await Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
  ]).then(async([aa, bb]) => {
    const a =  aa.json();
    const b =  bb.json();
    return [a, b]
  })
  .then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);

  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Using `Promise.all` to fetch the json responses of each of the API's-

**CODE:**

```
Promise.all([
  API_1_Promise,
  API_2_Promise,
  API_3_Promise])
  .then(allResults => console.log(allResults))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

In which `API_1_Promise,API_2_Promise,API_3_Promise` is defined as

```
API_1_Promise = fetch(`API_URL_1`, {  *Add required headers* }).then(response => response.json())

API_2_Promise = fetch(`API_URL_2`, {  *Add required headers* }).then(response => response.json())

API_3_Promise = fetch(`API_URL_3`, { *Add required headers* }).then(response => response.json())
```

**RESPONSE:**
This will print the array of responses from all the API calls
In console-->

```
[JSON_RESPONSE_API1, JSON_RESPONSE_API2, JSON_RESPONSE_API3]
```