# Extracting JSON data from fetch promises using Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch, async.js

I'm writing a `then()` statement for extracting the json data from an array of responses from `fetch()`. In the code below `queries` is an array of promises returned by a series of calls to `fetch()`. I'm using async/await for the response because otherwise the promises would be returned without resolving (I found a solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896470/how-to-return-the-promise-all-fetch-api-json-data)).

My first attempt worked properly, when I push into `jsonified` I obtain an array with the promises as elements:

```
return Promise.all(queries)
.then(async(responses)=> {
    let jsonified = [];
    for (let res of responses){
        jsonified.push(await(res.json()));
    }
    return jsonified;
}.then(data=> ...
```

But when I went for refactoring and tried to use `Array.reduce()` I realised that when I push into the accumulator instead of obtaining an array with a promise as element, acc is **assigned to be a promise instead**.

```
.then(responses=> {
    return responses.reduce(async(acc, next) => {
        acc.push(await(next.json()));
        return acc;
    }, [])
})
```

I can use the first version without any issue and the program works properly, but whats happening inside `Array.reduce()`? **Why pushing a promise into the accumulator returns a promise intead of an array?** How could I refactor the code with `Array.reduce()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the accumulator's initial value be a Promise that resolves to an empty array, then `await` the accumulator on each iteration (so that all prior iterations resolve before the current iteration runs)

```
.then(responses=> {
    return responses.reduce(async (accPromiseFromLastIter, next) => {
       const arr = await accPromiseFromLastIter;
       arr.push(await next.json());
       return arr;
    }, Promise.resolve([]))
})
```

(That said, your original code is a lot clearer, I'd prefer it over the `.reduce` version)

Live demo:

```js
const makeProm = num => Promise.resolve(num * 2);

const result = [1, 2, 3].reduce(async(accPromiseFromLastIter, next) => {
  const arr = await accPromiseFromLastIter;
  arr.push(await makeProm(next));
  return arr;
}, Promise.resolve([]));

result.then(console.log);
```

Unless you *have* to retrieve all data in serial, consider using `Promise.all` to call the `.json()` of each Promise in parallel instead, so that the result is produced more quickly:

```
return Promise.all(queries)
.then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json())));
```

If the queries are an array of `Response`s that were just generated from `fetch`, it would be even better to chain the `.json()` call onto the original `fetch` call instead, eg:

```
const urls = [ ... ];
const results = await Promise.all(
  urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
);
```

This way, you can consume the responses *immediately* when they come back, rather than having to wait for *all* responses to come back before starting to process the first one.

Comment: I went with the last suggestion, passing the fetch promises as soon as they're individually ready.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not what you've asked, you could avoid the pain of having to use `reduce`, and just utilise the `Promise.all()` that you are already using:

```
return Promise.all(queries.map(q => q.then(res => res.json()))
  .then(data => {...})
```

It's a much shorter way and less of a headache to read when you come back to it.