# JS 'await is only valid in async function' in Promise.all() function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to make a bunch of request an await to all of them to be completed with a Promise.all() function, but instead of doing manually all the fetchs like this:

```
var data = await Promise.all([
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((response) => response.json()),
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').then((response) => response.json()),
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response) => response.json())
      ]);
```

i want to make it dynamic, to make N fetch requests like this:

```
       let promiseList = [];
        try {
            for (let url of requestUrls) {
                promiseList.push(fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()));
            }

            var data = await Promise.all(promiseList);
```

But i get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` in the `await Promise.all()` line, if i delete the await, i get a `Promise {<pending>}` and
`(index):79 error:TypeError: data is not iterable`

This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/ham7g82e/1/

What i'm missing to get the data from those fetchs?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: You should use `.map()`

Comment: Your parent function to `await` doesn't have the `async` operator such as `async function myFunc(){ ... }`, we need to see how you defined the wrapping function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use await, instead use Promise.then

```
Promise.all(promiseList).then(data => {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
  console.log(data);

  for (var i of data) {
    console.log(`RESPONSE ITEM \n`);
      for (var obj of i) {
        console.log(obj);

      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To use await, it needs to be part of an async function.

```
async function functionName() {
 //You can use await in here, because you used the async keyword
}
```

Comment: Functions and methods both are functions in JavaScript.

Comment: functions are methods of the window object, so there isn't a distinction

Comment: Thank you! I did not learn JS formally. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If the function where are executing this code is not async, you could just use the .then() to get the values from the promises. There is not need to use await.

Check this documentation: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)