# How to wait for all Promise.all() to finish and then continue with the results

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I know this question is not the first asked here but I tried to work with other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all) but my code is not working as expected. I have a **Promise.all** where I have multiple fetch. The result of the fetch I turn into a json and then goon. When everything is done it should print "done" and of course more code to come. However, what happens is, that "done" is printed right away and then one by one the result of the fetches come in.

Here is my code:

```
  Promise.all(selectedTypes.map((type) => {
    let body = {
      selectedScreenshot: type,
      dataUrl: dataUrl
    };
    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.json()); //  this is done one by one as the results come in
      console.log('next');
    })
    }
  )).then(text => {
    console.log('done'); // this should be printed last, is printed first
  })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `.map()` callback -> `return fetch()`

Comment: And also no `return` in the "inner" `.then()`

Comment: @Andreas could you show me how I would add the returns so the Promise.all() is done and then the outer .then() prints something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `fetch` and return some result in `fetch().then()` and here is some helpful information and examples for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
selectedTypes = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2"]; // My example
Promise.all(selectedTypes.map((type) => {
    let body = {
        //selectedScreenshot: type,
        //dataUrl: dataUrl
    };
    var URL = type;
    //You need to return the fetch
    return fetch(URL, {
        // method: 'POST',
        // body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }).then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data); //  this is done one by one as the results come in
                console.log('next');
                // you need to return the data
                return data;
            });
}
)).then(text => {
    text.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log('FROM PROMISE ALL');
        console.log(item);
    });
    console.log('done'); // this should be printed last, is printed first
});
```

> I have added some json links just for example and commented everything that is not declared in your question

Comment: Do you need more examples ? Simply put if you dont return anything the promise is resolved `Promise.all([function () {
                2 + 2;
            }]).then(data => {
                console.log("resolved");
            });`