# Spread Operator not copying results in React

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to update setState in a for loop, but for some reason state isn't being copied it's just being replaced. There should be 2 clients, instead I am getting one. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? The console.log is returning both clients.

```
const handleViewClients = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
      console.log(clients[i].clientid);
      fetch("http://localhost:3005/all-clients/" + clients[i].clientid)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          setBarbersClient({
            ...barbersClient,
            client: result,
          });
        });
    }
  };
```

I have also tried this... The console.log is returning what I need

```
 Promise.all(
      clients.map((client) =>
        fetch("http://localhost:3005/all-clients/" + client.clientid)
      )
    )
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.username)
        setBarbersClient({
          ...barbersClient,
          client: result,
        });
        
      });
```

Here is the route from the server side

```
app.get("/all-clients/:clientid", (req, res) => {
  db.NewClientsx.findOne({
    where: {
      id: req.params.clientid,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    res.json(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: 2 `client` on your state?

Comment: If I console.log result.username which is the key of the clients, it returns both clients to the console. But for some reason after I set to state only one is there @bertdida

Comment: Will you be able to include the `/all-clients` response on your question?

Comment: yes it is there now @bertdida

Comment: What I mean on `response` is the actual `json` data - the data you'll see when you `console.log(result)`, is that something you can include?

Comment: I'd rather not because it has information I don't want public at the moment. an example would be 2 different objects containing client information such as {id: 1, username: johndoe, etc}

Answer (score 0):

There some fundamental concepts of sync vs. async code that you aren't accounting for here. State changing (and fetching) is asynchronous, so it won't run until **after** this synchronous loop has finished being executed (during which the state value will remain unchanged). Also, it's a bad idea to change state in a loop, for this reason and others.

Fetch all the clients, then do one state change at the end with *all* the fetched data. You can utilise things like `Promise.all` and `Promise.spread` to achieve this. Here's an example of doing multiple fetches then dealing with the results in one batch: [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)

Comment: I have added the updated code using promise.all at the top, still getting the same problem. Just returning one client. Thanks for the small lesson on async and sync @Jayce444

Comment: @Jayg713 `Promise.all` returns an array of results, so you shouldn't be calling `resp.json()` on that array. Print out each step in the `.then`, before adding each new one. Start with the `Promise.all(...).then(res => console.log(res))` and go from there

Comment: I do need to call resp.json() otherwise it returns a non json array with headers and status codes, not the information that i need. When i console.log result.username it returns both clients, But when it is set to state only one client is there. I have even tried setting it in redux, same problem @Jayce444

Answer (score 0):

You're making two distinct mistakes of which either is enough to cause the behaviour you're seeing.

#### 1. You're overwriting the `client` property.

Every time you call the setter function you're overwriting the previous value of the `client` property. You'll need some data structure that supports multiple values like a map:

```
setBarbersClient({
  ...barbersClient,
  clients: {
    ...barbersClient.clients,
    [result.id]: result
  },
});
```

You will need to change your render logic somewhat to accomodate the new data structure.

#### 2. You're using a stale reference.

When you access `barbersClient` its setter may have already been called with a different value and your reference to it still refers to the value of the previous run of the render function. You can make sure your reference is fresh by using a set state action callback.

```
setBarbersClient(previousValue => {
  ...previousValue,
  clients: {
    ...previousValue.clients,
    [result.id]: result
  },
});
```

`previousValue` will never be stale inside the set state action function body.