# loading Mutiple URLS JSON using fetch in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, url, fetch

I am attempting to fetch multiples URLs in React.js using the Promise.all() method, how can I do that?

So I got this code from another stack forum. And I need to take inside all urls list, like json, and pass to an state called "SetBusStop":

```
const requests = urls.map(url => 
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
 const toBus = responses => 
 responses.map(response => response);
  Promise.all(requests).then(toBus)
 .then(positions => {setBusStop(positions));
```

And these are the const urls links:

````
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=8",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=9",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=3",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=7",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=1",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=2",
   "https://aiko-olhovivo-proxy.aikodigital.io/Parada/BuscarParadasPorCorredor?codigoCorredor=10"
  ]; ```

I'm so stuck, thanks.
````

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711496/2610061

Answer (score 2):

```
// Example urls
 const urls = [
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3",
];

const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url))

Promise.all(requests)
  .then((responses) => {  // Array of response object
    return Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()))  // converting response to json
  })
  .then((responsesData) => {  // actual array of data returned from response.json()
    setBusStop(responsesData)
  })


Result:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "suite": "Apt. 556",
        "city": "Gwenborough",
        "zipcode": "92998-3874",
        "geo": { "lat": "-37.3159", "lng": "81.1496" }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
        "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
        "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
        "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "address": {
        "street": "Victor Plains",
        "suite": "Suite 879",
        "city": "Wisokyburgh",
        "zipcode": "90566-7771",
        "geo": { "lat": "-43.9509", "lng": "-34.4618" }
        },
        "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
        "company": {
        "name": "Deckow-Crist",
        "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
        "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Clementine Bauch",
        "username": "Samantha",
        "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
        "address": {
        "street": "Douglas Extension",
        "suite": "Suite 847",
        "city": "McKenziehaven",
        "zipcode": "59590-4157",
        "geo": { "lat": "-68.6102", "lng": "-47.0653" }
        },
        "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
        "website": "ramiro.info",
        "company": {
        "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
        "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
        "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet with a different URL, as I do not have authorisation to use yours. Maybe this can be helpful to you?

```js
Promise.all(
  [1,2,3,7,8,9,10]
  .map(                   // collate an array of promises here ...
    i=>fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+i)
       .then(r=>r.json()) // set each promise to deliver a json
  )
).then(users=>console.log(users.map(u=>u.id+' '+u.name))); // process all results
```

Please keep in mind that `Promise.all()` will "fail fast", i. e. it will `reject` the whole promise as soon as *one rejection* within the array of promises has been received.