# How can I fetch an array of URLs without Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This question is the same as
[How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31710768) *except* that I want an answer that
does *not* use `Promise.all`.
<sup>1</sup>

The array of URLs:

```js
urls = ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3']
```

The JSONs of the URLs:

```json
{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
 "completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":3,"title":"fugiat veniam minus","completed":false}
```

The goal is to get an array of objects, where each object contains the `title`
value from the corresponding URL.

To make it a little more interesting, I will assume that there is already an
array of *names* that I want the array of *titles* to be merged with:

```js
namesonly = ['two', 'three']
```

The desired output is an array of objects:

```js
[{"name":"two","loremipsum":"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui"},
{"name":"three","loremipsum":"fugiat veniam minus"}]
```

where I have changed the attribute name `title` to `loremipsum`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The specific reason I want a solution *not* using `Promise.all`
is that I want JavaScript code that works in Postman scripts.
The latter don't (yet) support promises natively, at the time of writing.

Comment: Any particular reason `Promise.all` shouldn't be used?

Comment: The reason is in the footnote. Still, the question itself has nothing to do with Postman.

Comment: Ah, I missed the footnote. So, What does postman actually do when fetching, in that case?

Comment: This risks getting off-topic but ..., Postman uses something called _pm objects_ instead of promises, unfortunately.

Comment: I think it's relevant because maybe there is an alternative solution. However, I need to know how exactly it handles async in order to figure out if there is one and if so, what is it.

Comment: Is [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts) how one should make requests with Postman?

Comment: _Is this how one should make requests with Postman?_ - YES!

Comment: Here is a
[link saying pm.sendRequest returns a _pm object_ instead of a promise](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3927).
I _can_ use promises in Postman scripts (since it is just JavaScript), but certain native functions can not be called from within the "callback" of a Promise, most notably `pm.visualizer.set()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution relies on the second Stack Snippet of
[this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002).
<sup>1</sup>

```js
const namesonly = ['two', 'three'];
const urls = ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3'];

const titles = [];
let countDown = urls.length;
urls.forEach((url, index) => {
  asynchronousCall(url, title => {
    titles[index] = title;
    if (--countDown === 0) { // Callback for ALL starts on next line.
      const names = namesonly.map(value => ({ name: value }));
      const fakeLatins = titles.map(value => ({ loremipsum: value }));
      const result =
        names.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, fakeLatins[i]));
      console.log('result:\n' + JSON.stringify(result));
    }
  });
});
function asynchronousCall (url, callback) {
  console.log('Starting fetch for "' + url + '".');
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(responseBody => {
    console.log(url.slice(-1) + ': ' + responseBody.title + ' ...');
    console.log('... fetch for ' + url + ' completed!');
    callback(responseBody.title); // Individual callback.
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### References

- [Closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337)
- [Start many asynchronous calls and wait for them all – 2nd Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002)

---

<sup>1</sup> I have deliberately left a lot of printouts in the code.
The purpose is to make it easier to see what is happening and in what order.
Anyone considering to use the code should of course remove some or all of the
printouts.