# How do you fetch multiple pages of data into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, fetch

**Here is my code**

```
let url;
let planetCount;
let planetData = [];

//turn through the pages
for (let p = 1; p < 7; p++) {
  url = `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${p}`;

  //fetch data
  for (let j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {

        //push data to array
        for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
          planetData.push(data.results[i]);
        }
      })

    console.log(planetData)

  }
}
```

**And here is the output:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hivwr.png

**Problem**: How do I make it so it all goes into one array, instead of 6?

Comment: your `console.log` is still in a for loop so you display 6 times same array, but each time this array is empty

Comment: You have a console.log in your first for loop that runs 6 times. I think the code looks correct otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have only one array. You just get an output six times because you run `console.log()` within a loop.

I expanded your code with the proper way to handle several async calls and wait until they are all finished:

```js
let url;
let planetCount;
let planetData = []
let promises = [];

//turn through the pages
for (let p = 1; p < 7; p++) {
url = `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${p}`;

//fetch data
for (let j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    promises.push(fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

            //push data to array
            for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                planetData = planetData.concat(data.results[i]);
            }

        }));
    }
}

Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => {
    console.log(planetData.length, '=>', planetData);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` and `Promise.all()` to return an array of the pages returned. Once we have this, we can use `Array.flat()` to create a contiguous array of planet data:

```js
async function getPlanets() {
    const urls = Array.from( { length: 7 }, (v,i) => `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${i + 1}` );
    const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.results));
    const planetData = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat();
    console.log(`Results for ${planetData.length} planets downloaded...`);
    console.log('Results:', planetData);
}

getPlanets()
```

Comment: This is extremely beautiful! I tried to stay as close as possible to the original code to not add additional reading-complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)

Promise all should be the right tool for you to use so that you wait until all promises are resolved before handling responses

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how async code works.

the `fetch()` function will eventually return a result, but that result is not available at the time you are trying to log it.

You must wait for the result to be retrieved. Use `Aysnc/Await` to accomplish that:

```js
async function turnThroughThePges() {
  let url;
  let planetCount;
  let planetData = [];


  //turn through the pages
  for (let p = 1; p < 7; p++) {
    url = `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${p}`;
    //fetch data
    for (let j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            planetData.push(data.results[i]);
          }
        })
    }
  }
  return planetData;
}

turnThroughThePges().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
let url;
let promises = [];

//turn through the pages
for (let p = 1; p < 7; p++) {
  url = `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${p}`;

  //fetch data
  promises.push(
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data.results)
  );
}

function handleRejection(p) {
  return p.catch((err) => ({ error: err }));
}
async function requests() {
  return await Promise.all(promises.map(handleRejection));
}
requests().then((planetData) => console.log(planetData.flat()));
```